# Invalid data source in QGIS 2.18

Tags: python, raster, pyqgis, qgis-2.18, raster-conversion

I am trying to run the raster process in QGIS 2.18. and every time I am getting an error as "Data source is invalid". What should I do?

Python error that I am getting:

```
2018-09-24T13:56:09 1   warning:C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py:607: ImportWarning: Not importing directory 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\test': missing __init__.py
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level) 
        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 298, in loadPlugin
            __import__(packageName)
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
            from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 31, in <module>
            from processing.core.Processing import Processing
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 62, in <module>
            from processing.algs.saga.SagaAlgorithmProvider import SagaAlgorithmProvider
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\saga\SagaAlgorithmProvider.py", line 33, in <module>
            from SagaAlgorithm import SagaAlgorithm
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\saga\SagaAlgorithm.py", line 20, in <module>
            standard_library.install_aliases()
          File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\future\standard_library\__init__.py", line 483, in install_aliases
            import test
```